# two cloned select box not loaded if i remove alert

Tags: jquery, grails, postback, gsp, clonenode

[image]

I have couple of issues-
the first constraint on select is loaded when reference table value selected.

**ISSUE 1** - The last two select box name -Constraint on should have cloned option     from first constraint on.but should not have the selected option in previous     select box. How to do it?

**ISSUE 2** - My select box is loaded on javascript call but i have to add a alert for this,why?
Code for population two select -

```
function LoadSelects()
{
 $("#columns2 option").each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
 $("#columns3 option").each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
   alert("i m called");  ///it does not load the selects if i remove this****why?
 $("#columns option").clone().appendTo("#columns2");
  $("#columns option").clone().appendTo("#columns3");
 }  
}
```

Controller code for population first select-

```
 def getColumns = {
    def columns = GGWSchemaXref.executeQuery("select distinct p.columnname     from GGWSchemaXref p where p.tablename=:table and p.dbname = 'IVR_GUARDIAN'",[table:params.tableCombo])
    render(template:"selectTemplate", model: [ columnList: columns ])

}
```

GSP page code here-

```
  <tr> <td>Reference Table:</td>
   <td><g:select name="tableCombo"
        noSelection="${['':message(code:'Select Table')]}"
        from="${result}" value="${tableName }"        onchange="${remoteFunction(action:'getColumns', update:'columns', params:'\'tableCombo=\'    + this.value', OnComplete = 'LoadSelects();')}"/> </td></tr>
 <tr id ="cons"><td nowrap>Constraint On:</td>
    <td nowrap><g:select name="columns" from="[]" /></td>
    <td nowrap>Constraint Value:</td>
    <td nowrap><g:textField name="columnValue" value="${enterVal }" />  
</tr>
 <tr id ="cons2"><td nowrap>Constraint On:</td>
    <td nowrap><g:select name="columns2" from="[]" /></td>
    <td nowrap>Constraint Value:</td>
    <td nowrap><g:textField name="columnValue2" value="${enterVal2 }" />  
</tr> 
 <tr id ="cons3"><td nowrap>Constraint On:</td>
    <td nowrap><g:select name="columns3" from="[]" /></td>
    <td nowrap>Constraint Value:</td>
    <td nowrap><g:textField name="columnValue3" value="${enterVal3 }" />  
</tr>
```

**ISSUE 3-** I need to keep the selected and entered values after search (post back).

Please help how to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first "A" in AJAX is for "asynchronous". You need to execute `LoadSelects()` in the success callback of your ajax

You can simplify the function to:

```
function LoadSelects(){

    $("#columns2, #columns3").html( $("#columns").html()).val('') ;

 }
```

This will copy the options from `#columns` to both of the other selects and unselect both which I believe is what you are asking.

Using `$('select').val('')` as in code above will remove `selected` property from options

**Edit**  If the `each` you are using for your selects is due to have more than one with same ID you have a problem since ID's must be unique. If this is the case, code will need to be refactored to a traverse within a row

**EDIT #2 AJAX Success**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'tableCombo=' + this.value,
    url: '/GryphonMonitor/load/getColumns',

    success: function(data, textStatus) {‌

        /*  this is callback when all data has been received*/      

        jQuery('#columns').html(data);
         LoadSelects();
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, ‌errorThrown) {}
})
```

Comment: thanks for reply Charlie.i am new to jquery & your suggested loadSelects() is doing the work what i wanted with just a line,awesome!!. but still need to add alert.what do you mean"You need to execute LoadSelects() in the success callback of your ajax" i tried calling onSuccess but still the same issue.

Comment: <select name="tableCombo" onchange="jQuery.ajax({type:&#39;POST&#39;,data:&#39;tableCombo=&#39; + this.value, url:&#39;/GryphonMonitor/load/getColumns&#39;,success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery(&#39;#columns&#39;).html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});" id="tableCombo" >

Comment: adde another edt regarding ajax success callback

Comment: thanks again.managed to  get it anyhow.not looking nice though.I called the loadselect on first select click. But other issue associated is on post back all the selected values are lost and reset to first option.

Comment: sorry I missed your edit 2.thanks for your time . my issues 1,2 is resolved with your code .still trying to get all values on post back page.

Comment: got it working on postback. used a small script on postback.      if (selectedId) {
                    $('#columns option[value=' + selectedId + "]")[0].selected = true;
                  } else {
                    $('columns').selectedIndex = 0;
                  }                                                                thanks .